# I have added two videos next to each other using col property but in small screens it gets stacked without spacing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The videos got stacked one below another without any space. How can i create spacing in between them when using small device

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-md-offset-2">
    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3">
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/qLCLvzTGFVM" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3">
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/lR_aZWdxNV8" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1) You can add .form-group class (which will give margin-bottom of 1rem) to both your div with col-xs-12 class like:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-md-offset-2 form-group">
    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3">
       <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/qLCLvzTGFVM" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 form-group">
    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3">
      <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/lR_aZWdxNV8" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

2) Or you can add a [bootstrap spacing utility class](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/spacing/) like .mb-2 class (which adds a bottom margin) to both your div with col-xs-12 class like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-md-offset-2 mb-2">
    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3">
       <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/qLCLvzTGFVM" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 mb-2">
    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3">
      <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/lR_aZWdxNV8" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try adding the class mt-4 for a top margin or mb-4 for a bottom margin to the cols. Like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-md-offset-2 mt-4">
        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3">
            <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/qLCLvzTGFVM" frameborder="0"
                allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
                allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 mt-4">
        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3">
            <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/lR_aZWdxNV8" frameborder="0"
                allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
                allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```